# Will mapping a Team Foundation Server Project to my local path workspace overwrite my local files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

So I created a new Team Foundation Server project a while back and checked in project source code. Over time, development was engaged without actually having a mapped local version to my project on TFS.

I am now ready to map my local path workspace to TFS source control for the project, when I do that I will be asked to get Latest Version.

Will this overwrite my local files?

I have done this before and I swear it has over written my local files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will overwrite your files. If there is a specific reason for keeping the existing files in that directory, create a new workspace and map the project to a different local directory on your local disk.

Comment: Just the convenience of connecting to my local workspace with my latest changes is the only reason. I just copied my code to another directory and pasted over after getting latest.

Comment: I messed up here and didn't know it will overwrite my current files. I did no backup. Any way i can get the previous code back?

Comment: If the only code that you had was local to your hard drive, no.