# TFS Mapping lost local code

Tags: tfs

I have a solution on TFS "Project One".

"Project One" was copied via external to another device of mine and i needed to map the solution on the new device to source control. Once i mapped the project, it replaced all the source that was local with whatever was last on TFS for the project. Any way i can get my local source back or is it gone forever?

I had not done any backups on the local code as i didn't think it would delete my current source. In fact i thought it would as me to do a merge.

I had a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697302/will-mapping-a-team-foundation-server-project-to-my-local-path-workspace-overwri/25699117#25699117) after my code had been replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you've lost the changes as TFS has overwritten the local files.  You set up the workspace after making the changes so TFS didn't know anything about them in order to merge.

If you created any additional files that weren't under source control then they should still exist locally, so maybe you haven't lost everything

In future, if you setup the workspace first then you can obviously make changes to the files and TFS will know about it.

Alternatively, map the workspace to a different local folder and then copy in your changes.  If you are using a local workspace then TFS will generate the pending changes for you.